# Meaning of '\0\0' in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm looking at a 3rd party API and they have the following piece of code:

```
def array_u16 (n): return array('H', '\0\0'*n)
```

I understand that `'\0'` means `NULL`, does `'\0\0'` have any special meaning or does it just mean 2 `NULL`s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It just assures that two bytes are provided `n` times so the size of the array will be equal to `n`. If `'\0'` was provided, the resulting array would have a `size == n//2` ([due to the type-code `'H'` requiring `2` bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/array.html#module-array)); that is obviously counter intuitive:

```
>>> array('H', '\0' * 10)    # 5 elements
array('H', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> array('H', '\0\0' * 10)  # 10 elements
array('H', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Note that, in Python `3`, if you need the *same* snippet to work you **must** [provide a *`bytes` object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) as the `initializer` argument to `array`:

```
>>> array('H', b'\0\0' * 10)   
array('H', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

As you also can't provide a `u''` string in Python 2. Other than that, the behavior stays exactly the same.

So `'\0\0'` is for convenience reasons, nothing more. No semantics are attached to `'\0\0'`.

<sub>No semantics are really attached to `'\0'` either (as they do in, for example, `C`) `'\0'` *is just another string in Python*.</sub>

---

As a further example for this behavior, take the initialization of an array with a type-code of `'I'` for unsigned ints  with a minimum of `2` bytes but `4` on `64bit` builds of Python.

In the spirit of the snippet you've provided, you'd initialize the array by doing something like this:

```
>>> array('I', b'\0\0\0\0' * 10)
array('I', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Yes, four times the `b'\0'` string to get `10` elements.

---

As a *final* note -- *the following timings are performed on Python 3 but 2 is the same* -- you might be wondering why he used `'\0\0\' * n` instead of the more intuitive-looking `[0] * n` to initialize the array. Well, it's quite faster:

```
n = 10000
%timeit array('I', [0]*n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop

%timeit array('I', b'\0\0\0\0'* n)
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.36 µs per loop
```

Of course, you can do better (for type-codes other than `'b'`) by feeding a `bytearray` to `array`. One way to initialize [a `bytearray` is by providing an `int` as the number of items to initialize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray) with null bytes:

```
%timeit array('I', bytearray(n))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 µs per loop
```

but, if I remember correctly, the `bytearray(int)` way of initializing a bytearray might get deprecated in `3.7+` :-).

Answer (score 10):

The [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/array.html) class accepts a format character (called a typecode) followed by an initializer. `H` means an unsigned short, with a minimum size of 2 bytes so, `'\0\0'` satisfies that. The `* n` part is to initialize the entire array to NULL bytes.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this function returns an array made of 16-bits; thus `\0\0` probably stands for creating two bytes (which is 16 bits) of data. In other words, it returns n words of two bytes.